# BASH: replace groups in a string using sed

Tags: regex, bash, sed

Contents contains a string that was read from a file. What I want to do is to replace the capture groups with the groups and a newline character. But I don't know how.

This works

```
contents=$(echo $contents | sed -e 's|/$(#.*)\n||g')
```

But this doesn't

```
contents=$(echo $contents | sed -e 's|/$(#.*)\n|\1\n|g')
ERROR: sed: -e expression #1, char 18: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS
```

And neither does this

```
contents=$(echo $contents | sed -er 's|/$(#.*)\n|\1\n|g')
ERROR: sed: can't read s|/$(#.*)\n|\1\n|g: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Please provide example input and desired output.

Comment: Is `$` being treated as the special "end of line" character? In which case, nothing is being matched.... You'd need to escape the character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If content is multiline `$content` must be between double quotes to avoid splitting: `$` has a special meaning in regex it's the end of line anchor, must be escaped. Group parentheses must be escaped (except with `-r` extended regex). Also `\n` is not matched `$` can be used instead.

```
content=$(echo "$content"|sed -e 's|/\$\(#.*\)$|\1|g')
```